# Custom Labels and $Label

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, customlabel, label

I am not sure what is happening behind this $Label line:

```
<aura:component controller="CommunityHoldingDetailController" >
    <aura:attribute name="holding" type="Holding__c" required="true" />
    <aura:attribute name="showDetail" type="boolean" default="true" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="this" action="{!c.getProperties}" />    

    <p class="slds-text-heading--label slds-truncate">{!$Label.c.Estimated_Appreciation_to_Date}</p>
```

The `Estimated_Appreciation_to_Date` is a custom label. I am not sure why it is displaying like this:

[image]

Is there anything else I need to do permissions wise or coding wise to get this label to display correctly?

[image]

Comment: Is this code snippet in an aura component (.cmp file)?

Comment: Are you sure you're using Aura components, not Web components?

Comment: @JayantDas yes I am using an aura component

Comment: @sfdcfox it's an aura component, I updated the post with some more code of the component